# My "list index out of range" problem in PYTHON

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

```py
total_task=float(input("Enter the assigned total task length(in half-hour(s)):"))
total_len=total_task*2
leng=int(total_len)
payments=[]
hours=[]
for i in range(leng):
    print("Enter the payment value( in TL) for task portion ID ",(i+1)," having length ",((i+1)*0.5)," hour(s):")
    portionLen=int(input())
    payments.append(portionLen)
    hours.append(portionLen)
paymentsTable=[]
for i in range(leng):
    paymentsRow=[]
    for j in range(leng):
        paymentsRow.append(0)
    paymentsTable.append(paymentsRow)
for i in range(leng):
    paymentsTable[i][i]=payments[i]
for i in range(leng):
    for j in range(1,leng+1):
        maxPayment=0
        for k in range(j):
            pay=paymentsTable[i][k]+paymentsTable[k+1][j]
            if(pay>maxPayment):
                maxPayment=pay
        paymentsTable[i][j]=maxPayment
idTable=[]
for i in range(leng):
    idTableRow=[]
    for j in range(leng):
        idTableRow.append(0)
    idTable.append(idTableRow)
for i in range(leng):
    idTable[i][i]=i+1
for i in range(leng):
    for j in range(1,leng+1):
        maxPayment=0
        for k in range(j):
            pay = paymentsTable[i][k] + paymentsTable[k + 1][j]
            if (pay > maxPayment):
                maxPayment = pay
        paymentsTable[i][j] = maxPayment
for i in range(leng):
    for j in range(1,leng+1):
        maxPayment=0
        for k in range(j):
            pay = paymentsTable[i][k] + paymentsTable[k + 1][j]
            if (pay > maxPayment):
                maxPayment = pay
                idTable[i][j]=k+1
```

**My Sample input**

```
Enter the assigned total task length(in half-hour(s)):**2**
Enter the payment value( in TL) for task portion ID  1  having length  0.5  hour(s):
**100**
Enter the payment value( in TL) for task portion ID  2  having length  1.0  hour(s):
**400**
Enter the payment value( in TL) for task portion ID  3  having length  1.5  hour(s):
**500**
Enter the payment value( in TL) for task portion ID  4  having length  2.0  hour(s):
**600**
```

**and my sample error**

```py
line 23, in <module>
    pay=paymentsTable[i][k]+paymentsTable[k+1][j]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: for j in range(1,leng+1): this line is wrong. The length of paymentsTable is leng, but you try to access to index out of range of paymentsTable

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The error message you attached is pretty clear:

> in line 23, either `paymentsTable[i][k]` or `paymentsTable[k+1][j]`
> has an index out of range.

`paymentsTable` has exactly `leng` elements, so their valid indices go from `0` to `leng-1`.

Every element `paymentsTable[i]` is also a list with exactly `leng` elements, so their valid indices also go from `0` to `leng-1`.

Now, `i` ranges inside `range(leng)`, but `j` is ranging over `(range(1, leng + 1))`, which means the first value will be `1` and the last will be `leng`.

Hence, in the last iteration of `for j in range(1,leng+1)`, `j` is `leng` and the last valid index of `paymentsTable[i]` was `leng-1`, so you get the "IndexError: list index out of range"

Moreover, `k+1` also gets the value `leng` in the last iteration of that line, it is also out of range, considering that the last valid index of `paymentsTable` is also `leng`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this yet but I think the problem is with the row assignment. `paymentsRow` and `idTableRow` must be created outside the for a loop. Your implementation means it loops through and appends, but after appending, it makes the list empty again. So basically in your code, `paymentsRow` and `idTableRow` have only one element in them.

[UPDATE]
I integrated Rodrigo's solution with mine and no errors appeared.

```
total_task=float(input("Enter the assigned total task length(in half-hour(s)):"))
total_len=total_task*2
leng=int(total_len)
payments=[]
hours=[]
for i in range(leng):
    print("Enter the payment value( in TL) for task portion ID ",(i+1)," having length ",((i+1)*0.5)," hour(s):")
    portionLen=int(input())
    payments.append(portionLen)
    hours.append(portionLen)
paymentsTable=[]
paymentsRow=[]
for i in range(leng):
    for j in range(leng):
        paymentsRow.append(0)
    paymentsTable.append(paymentsRow)
for i in range(leng):
    paymentsTable[i][i]=payments[i]
for i in range(leng):
    for j in range(1,leng):
        maxPayment=0
        for k in range(j):
            pay=paymentsTable[i][k]+paymentsTable[k+1][j]
            if(pay>maxPayment):
                maxPayment=pay
        paymentsTable[i][j]=maxPayment
idTable=[]
idTableRow=[]

for i in range(leng):
    for j in range(leng):
        idTableRow.append(0)
    idTable.append(idTableRow)
for i in range(leng):
    idTable[i][i]=i+1
for i in range(leng):
    for j in range(1,leng):
        maxPayment=0
        for k in range(j):
            pay = paymentsTable[i][k] + paymentsTable[k + 1][j]
            if (pay > maxPayment):
                maxPayment = pay
        paymentsTable[i][j] = maxPayment
for i in range(leng):
    for j in range(1,leng):
        maxPayment=0
        for k in range(j):
            pay = paymentsTable[i][k] + paymentsTable[k + 1][j]
            if (pay > maxPayment):
                maxPayment = pay
                idTable[i][j]=k+1
```